# MobileConnect Functionalities and Questions

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobileconnect, sms

I am helping a client design and implement MobileConnect - and have come across some functionality issues and questions.  Can someone with MobileConnect expertise help with addressing all or some of these items?

- Client would like to be able to monitor ‘crisis messages’ from
  contacts – so either be able to monitor specific inbound texts, or
  extract these contacts and communicate with them somehow.  I know
  there is no 2-way messaging feature on MobileConnect, but are there
  other ways around this? Some way to monitor and extract by specific
  Keywords maybe? Client has Service Cloud so would like to route these
  messages over. I found these 2 potential solutions, looking for the
  most effective/simple solution though:

[Capture long customer reply to SMS sent with Mobile Connect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204440/capture-long-customer-reply-to-sms-sent-with-mobile-connect)

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_switch_to_live_support.htm&type=5

- If 2 people (2 subscriber keys) share the same mobile number and we
  are able to link them to our SFMC data model, then we use
  personalization in a SMS (e.g. referencing a ‘FirstName’ field in a
  linked DE), how will the personalization render? Which contact would
  win?
- Do we need the compliant message in every SMS (e.g. ‘4 msgs/mo.
  Reply STOP to quit, HELP for info. Msg & data rates may apply.’)?
- The compliant # of messages per month (e.g. 6msgs/mo) – does this include
  response or Next messages?
- Is it possible to set multiple blackout periods?
- Will sends slow down with large volumes? And around how long
  would it be, would throttling be required? (Client estimating sends
  may average between 100,000 to over a million contacts at once)
- Overall – client would like to understand capabilities, use cases,
  and limitations with keywords, so any other resources or
  documentation you have outside the Help documentation would be great
  to provide as well

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1) There are actually several 2-way messaging options available in MobileConnect. 
Check the availability of the SMS templates on that Account.

2) MobileConnect allows only one Contact to have one specific number as the Priority1 number. Meaning if this number also exists on some other Contact as Priority2 number, it is still/always sent to the Contact that has it as Priority1 and any personalization is also taken from that Contact attributes.

3) You do need to be compliant in all messages that are Marketing related, but Transactional messages can be treated in similar fashion as Transactional Emails. Though it really comes down to the specific country it is sent to.

4) Unclear what do you mean by compliant number of messages..

5) No, in MobileConnect you can have only one blackout window setting per BU.

6) Long Codes send 1 message per 1 second, Short Codes send 100 messages per 1 second. 
You do the math.